# breezeJS WebAPI and deploying to IIS dev server

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-web-api, breeze, hottowel, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm new to Breeze and webAPI for that matter.  I have a hopefully simple problem - 
While working locally my project works fine, but after I deploy to my dev server running IIS 7, I can't seem to get things to work.  My calls to Metadata work fine, but calls to any other action fail.  I get the lovely Http 500 error.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? - I can paste more code if need be.

Heres the guts of my controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class PALiveController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<PA_Trucks> _contextProvider =
        new EFContextProvider<PA_Trucks>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
}


    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<foodTrucks> Trucks()
    {
        var trucks= _contextProvider.Context.foodTrucks.Where(x => x.foodtype == "Tacos" || x.AcceptCredit == true);
        return trucks;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Have you looked in the network tab to see what the error message is?

Comment: If you can, try accessing your website from server itself, it should give you more info than "internal server error".